# Ruby on Rails controller performing unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using a controller to show a page that loads a 3D model in javascript. The problem I seem to be running into is that when I try to have javascript load the 3D model file ruby on rails instead tries to interpret it instead, using the name of the file as an ID.

the controller

```
def show
    @design = Design.find(params[:id])
end
```

The error log

> Started GET "/designs/slotted_disk" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-12 20:11:30 -0700 Processing by DesignsController#show as /
>
> Parameters: {"id"=>"slotted_disk"}
>
> User Load (0.2ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '...' LIMIT 1
>
> Design Load (0.1ms) SELECT "designs".* FROM "designs" WHERE "designs"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 [["id", "slotted_disk"]]
>
> Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Design with id=slotted_disk): app/controllers/designs_controller.rb:19:in `show'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use `find_by`.

```
def show
  @design = Design.find_by name: params[:id]
end
```

`find` always assumes that it's finding by the `id` column. `find_by` let's you find using a different column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command on your console

```
rake routes
```

My guess is your routes are configured to be such

`get devices/{id}` maps to `DeviceController`'s `Show` action

So when you do `devices/slotted_disk`, it treats `slotted_disk` as `id` parameter and lookup fails.

You need to configure a route to lookup by `device_type`. Try adding it in your `routes.rb`